# Questions using booleans?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console, console-application

I think its fairly obvious what I'm trying to accomplish but its also obvious that I'm new to coding. This is my code, it works fine until it gets to the "Would you like to run a program?" in which case it always acts like the user typed "yes". Am I going about this completely wrong or just writing it incorrectly?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string mystring = "What is your name?";
            Console.WriteLine(mystring);
            string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
            string Name = UserInput;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to run a program?");
            bool UserIput2;
            Console.ReadLine();
            bool Yes = true;
            bool No = false;
            if (UserIput2 = (true)) Console.WriteLine("What would you like to run? (Type help for a list of valid programs)");
            else if (UserIput2 = (false)) Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not assigning `UserIput2` to anything. You simply read in their answer, and discard the result

Comment: As an addition, you are assigning `UserIput2 = (true)` not comparing. So for comparison use `==`.    `UserIput2 == true` or if(UserInput2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, here I am assigning UserIput2 with input and comparing it with "yes" or "no". you can change it to your accordingly

```
 string mystring = "What is your name?";
        Console.WriteLine(mystring);
        string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
        string Name = UserInput;
        Console.WriteLine("Hello " + Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to run a program?");
        string UserIput2= Console.ReadLine();
        if (UserIput2.ToLower() == "yes") Console.WriteLine("What would you like to run? (Type help for a list of valid programs)");
        else if (UserIput2.ToLower() == "no") Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Alright .ToLower allows it to be lowercase but doesn't ignore case entirely. How would I make it ignore case? i.e. if someone typed YES and I still wanted it to read it. And secondly is this the most efficient method (using yes/no) or booleans more effective?

Answer (score 1):

In your current code you *discard* the user input:

```
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to run a program?");
bool UserIput2;
Console.ReadLine(); // <- input is discarded
```

Instead, you should *assign* it to `UserIput2`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to run a program?");

// we assume that answer is positive (UserIput2 == true) 
// if and only if user put "yes" in any register ("YES", "Yes", "yes"...)    
bool UserIput2 = String.Equals(
  Console.ReadLine(), 
  "yes", 
  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Another problem with `if`: `=` is *assigning*, not *comparing*:

```
 if (UserIput2 = (true)) Console.WriteLine(...);
```

means *assign `true` to `UserIput2` and then check*. The right implementation is

```
if (UserIput2) 
  Console.WriteLine("What would you like to run? (Type help for a list of valid programs)");
else 
  Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
```

Answer (score -1):

The `boolean` type is binary. Imagine that this type work like a light switch. It can have only 2 states - On `true` and Off `false`. Use this data type only for switching between two possible states.

Example C#:

```
bool result = (2 > 1); //Will result in true because 2 is great as 1

bool result = (2 < 1); //Will result in false because 2 is not less as 1
```